# Find the number of 3 digit numbers $xyz$ such that $x<y>z$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of 3 digit numbers $xyz$ such that $x<y>z$.

--
**My try**

Since x shouldn't be zero, $x>0$ and $y>1$. Let y=r where r=2,3,4...8,9  x can take r-1 values And z can take r values. 
For each value of r, $yz$ can take r(r-1) values. 
Am I correct? I'm struck here please help me.

Comment: Do you mean $x<y<z$ or $x<y$ and $z<y$?

Comment: You're right, hence the answer is $\sum\limits_{y=2}^{9}(y-1)y=240$. No need to denote $y$ with $r$ (the letter $y$ is "as good as" the letter $r$).

Comment: Yes AlgorithmsX sir

Comment: Excuse me Barack manos sir in ans.. You posted that ans.. is 168.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy: start with noticing that $y$ needs to be at least 1 so that something fits below it, that's 9 possibilities.

Given a particular $y$, the possible values for $x$ are 0 through $y-1$, that's $y$ different digits. The number of possible values of $z$ is the same.

So, if for example $y = 3$, there are 3 options for $x$ and 3 options for $z$. 9 combinations altogether.

We're not specifying what $y$ is but we've established that it's between 1 and 9, so the answer is

$$1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + 9^2 = 285.$$

**Edit**: sorry, didn't notice you meant nonzero digits. You can amend the above easily. It's

$$1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + 8^2 = 204.$$

Or do you also want them all different? That's another story. If you write the compound inequality as $x < y > z$ then $x$ can very well be $z$ (or not), this answer addresses the question as it is currently posed but I am happy to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well there are many solutions so it is not question of "the number" but "the numbers". In fact If $xyz$ is the integer then for $y=1,0$ there is no solution but for $3\le y\le9$ there are several solutions in each case. You have $y=2$ gives $1^2$  solutions, $y=3$ gives $2^2$ solutions,....$y=9$ gives $8^2$ solutions.

Comment: The OP already knows, correctly, that $y=r$ gives $r(r-1)$ solutions, not $(r-1)^2$.

Comment: $y$ gives $y-1$ possibilities for $x$ and so is for $z$ considering nonzero digits.

Comment: Why are you only considering nonzero digits for $z$?  The OP clearly wants to include numbers such as $xyz=120$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=r$ gives $r(r-1)$ possibilities for $x$ and $z$, with $2\le r\le9$, it's easy enough to add things up directly:

$$2\cdot1+3\cdot2+4\cdot3+5\cdot4+6\cdot5+7\cdot6+8\cdot7+9\cdot8=2+6+12+20+30+42+56+72=240$$

If you want to avoid doing all that arithmetic, then you need to know (or look up) some formulas for sums, such as $\sum_{k=1}^nk={n(n+1)\over2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2={k(k+1)(2k+1)\over6}$.  But even then, you wind up doing a bit of arithmetic.  It's not clear it's worth it, except possibly for the practice.